# Good practice for multi-publisher, multi-subscriber data exchange on Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, publish-subscribe, android-broadcast

I am working on sharing road traffic information between Android applications, and wondering what is a good transport mechanism.

There are two classes of applications: Publishers post traffic messages they have obtained from various sources (say, an Internet service or a TMC receiver device) and converted to a standard format. Subscribers listen for messages and work with them (e.g. displaying them in a list or guiding drivers around congestions). The system is intended to be decentral: there will be multiple publishers, multiple subscribers and users can mix and match them as they like.

Messages are identified by a unique ID, which remains stable over their entire life cycle. They have an expiration time, after which they are considered invalid. Until then, they can be updated at any time. An update can also cancel the message (replacing it with a tombstone until it expires), or extend its expiration time.

Subscribers get new messages as they arrive. (Filtering may happen in a later phase.) They also need a way to retrieve all currently cached messages from all publishers.

A message is around 1 kByte in size. A publisher can easily hold several hundred active messages at any given time.

In terms of security, the messages are generally public information. The only sensitive information is geodata, as it may allow for conclusions on the location of the device or where its user intends to travel. The precision of such data is low, anywhere from city to country level. Therefore I don’t see a need to hide this information from any app, as long as it has location permission.

Now I am wondering what a good transport mechanism would be:

## Option 1: Broadcast intents

Initially I have been working with broadcast intents: whenever a publisher has any new messages, it sends an implicit broadcast with the messages in the extras. Subscribers can register a broadcast receiver at run time to receive messages. They also have the option to send a poll broadcast (an explicit broadcast, with the corresponding broadcast receiver declared in the publisher’s Manifest). Publishers will then respond with a feed of all currently cached messages. To address security concerns, any app sending a broadcast with geodata requires that the receiver hold one of the location permissions.

There is an issue with large feeds, as the Android request broker supports a maximum of 1 MByte for all concurrent transactions (so the maximum amount of data in a feed can be even less if things are busy). I am currently working around that by breaking down feeds into chunks of 100 messages or less.

An advantage of this system is that all central infrastructure is provided by the OS. Having one publisher and one subscriber app installed is sufficient.

## Option 2: Content Providers

Some people have pointed out that broadcast intents are not the best way to go, and have suggested I implement a content provider, a territory into which I have not ventured so far. Looking at the documentation, it is not clear if there is a way to have multiple backends (each backend being a separate app) implement functionally identical content providers and advertise them as such. Since content providers support both read and write operations, I could set up one central component as the content provider, and have both publishers and subscribers connect to it. However, that would require providing a central component in order to work, which I would rather avoid.

Questions:

- Is there a way to implement the above multi-publisher, multi-subscriber model with content providers, and without having to supply a central component not already provided by the OS?
- Specifically, can a single content provider have multiple backends? Alternatively, can multiple, functionally identical content providers advertise themselves as a group?
- How would I implement the above using content providers?
- What are advantages and drawbacks of broadcast intents or content providers that I may have missed?

Comment: What Gabe and I suggested in [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57119867/how-to-prevent-transactiontoolargeexception-or-recover-from-it) was to replace the *extras* in your broadcast `Intent` with a `Uri` pointing to a `ContentProvider`. You would still use your existing broadcast mechanism, just with a second step to get the overly-large data. An analogy would be an email having an `<img src="...">` with a Web URL instead of having the overly-large image as an attachment.

Comment: Another analogy is with FCM for push messages. There, the payload is even more limited (4KB last I checked). That means the payload often is just a URL or identifier that can be used to fetch the rest of the data from a Web service. The answer isn't "oh, no! our data is over 4KB! we can't use FCM!" -- the answer is to use FCM for the push aspect and offload the bulk data delivery to something else that lacks the tight size limit.

Comment: @CommonsWare web URL won’t work as the payload data isn’t on the Web, and some sources (such as TMC) do not even require a data connection. So the main point of the question becomes: how do I get the actual message payload from one app to the other?

Comment: "web URL won’t work as the payload data isn’t on the Web" -- I understand that. I was drawing analogies, to help you understand what the recommendation was. "how do I get the actual message payload from one app to the other?" -- we recommended that you use a `ContentProvider`. Your broadcast system would remain mostly the same. Instead of the extra holding the big payload, the extra holds a `Uri` to a `ContentProvider`. The receiver would then use a `ContentResolver` to do something with that `Uri` (e.g., `query()`).

Comment: @CommonsWare so each app would implement its own content provider (following a common specification), and point to that in the broadcasts it sends out? That indeed sounds like an answer… why not make it one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to implement the above multi-publisher, multi-subscriber model with content providers

Keep the broadcasts. Replace the payload.

Publishers would implement a `ContentProvider` that serve up the current roster of messages. You can think of a `ContentProvider` as being a quirky sort of REST-style Web service, where `Uri` values get mapped to responses by the provider.

Publishers would then send broadcasts as they are today, but perhaps with only two extras:

- One that identifies the protocol version that the broadcast is using, since you have lots of independently-updated parties. Rceivers need to know how to interpret the broadcast, as you might change the rules over time.
- One that contains a `Uri` pointing to the publisher's `ContentProvider`.

If there are other extras that you are using today that you know will remain small, and you want to still put those in the broadcast, that's cool. Just keep the indeterminate-sized ones out of the broadcast.

Receivers would then:

- Look at the protocol version extra and branch to the code to handle that version (today, just one branch, but, hey, future-proofing)
- Use that `Uri` and a `ContentResolver` to get the messages (and other stuff if needed) from the publisher

You might consider developing this communications infrastructure as an SDK. Even if you are the only one developing apps, you'll want to avoid duplicating all this logic across the apps. And, if third parties will develop apps, you're better off giving them an SDK to work from, rather than forcing them "roll their own".